# Where to get all versions of x86 aka IA32 Instruction Set Architecture manuals

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I know about [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/). I also know that these cover all the legacy & old processor ISAs.

But I want the individual manual (*the one that released along with the processor*) for each of the processors.

I managed to find the [80386 manual](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/toc.htm)

**EDIT:**

I'm starting bounty.

Comment: Sign up as an Intel partner I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://www.rcollins.org/intel.doc/) contains links to several of the manuals, such as the [486 Developer's Manual](ftp://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/27302101.pdf) and others:

- [486 family](http://www.rcollins.org/intel.doc/486Manuals.html)
- [586 family](http://www.rcollins.org/intel.doc/586Manuals.html)
- [Pentium manuals](http://www.rcollins.org/intel.doc/686Manuals.html)
- [Pentium II manuals](http://www.rcollins.org/intel.doc/P2Manuals.html)

These pages include the developer's manual, errata, etc.  It doesn't seem to extend to modern processors, such as the Core series.

Intel has made a lot of processors.  Which other ones are you after?  "Each" is... a lot!

Comment: What's with the upvotes? Most of the links on that site are obsolete (broken). The author of the question has probably tried google too.

Comment: I tried several of the links and they all worked for me.  Just posting it since it seemed useful, is all :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are after juicy details 
about Pentium I and later processors
(such as instruction latencies),
check the nice document below:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf